# How to make a RichTextBox Transparent as well as Read-only Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, richtextbox, readonly, transparent

As soon as i set the readonly property to true,the Transparency of the RichTextBox becomes greyish, so my RichTextBox no longer looks transparent.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to extract the default control template for the RichTextBox using Expression Blend - it sounds like there's a trigger in there that's causing the greyness when the property changes, so just remove that and save the amended template to a Resource Dictionary in your solution.

I'd have a go at doing this for you, but I when I opened a new Silverlight project in Blend it didn't recognise RichTextBox - I'm guessing that I don't have a recent enough version of Silverlight installed since we only use WPF, no Silverlight.